# Accessing Kinect for Xbox 360 depth camera using PyKinect

Tags: python, computer-vision, kinect, openkinect

I am currently working on a project for identifying the position of objects for which I need to get access to Kinect's depth camera. However, I am unable to install PyKinect or any library like OpenKinect using pip. How can I get depth data from Kinect?